# Is the clock on the Apple Watch synchronized to a paired iPhone?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I record events on the Apple Watch, and use the timestamp `Double(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)` as event time. I do the same on a paired iPhone. Can I trust that the clocks are synchronized to a very high precision between the two devices? Ideally, I need to correlate the events between the two devices based on time.

I see some guides that describe calibrating the watch, but no true answer.
[Apple Dox 1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204516) , [Apple Dox 2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250794151)

The closest I've come was this [quote](https://www.macrumors.com/2015/12/30/apple-watch-precise-time-keeping/#:%7E:text=Apple%27s%20time%20servers%20communicate%20the,to%20provide%20the%20exact%20time.):

> Apple's time servers communicate the time to iPhones across the world, and the iPhone in turn syncs with the Apple Watch via Bluetooth to provide the exact time. Communicating a GPS signal from a server to an iPhone to an Apple Watch over Bluetooth has its own delays, which Apple corrects for via software. Apple's NTP servers make sure iPhones and Apple Watches keep time at "Stratum One" accuracy, within milliseconds of "Stratum Zero" devices.

Comment: Doesn't that quote answer your question: Your watch's clock will be synchronized within milliseconds of your phone.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Swift question. It's an Apple Watch question. The question would apply even if you're programming in PERL, Python, or COBOL (shudder).

Comment: @DuncanC not really. it's from a random website. was hoping someone had an official link or experience in this. && I've removed the swift flag